# setNeedsDisplay does not trigger drawRect in subviews as expected

Tags: objective-c, subview, drawrect, setneedsdisplay

I'm struggling with `setNeedsDisplay`. I thought it was supposed to trigger calls of `drawRect:` for the view for which it is called and the hierarchy below that if it's within the view's bounds, but I'm not finding that to be the case. Here is my setup:

From the application delegate, I create a view whose size is a square that covers essentially the whole screen real estate. This view is called `TrollCalendarView`. There is not much that happens with `TrollCalendarView` except for a rotation triggered by the compass.

There are 7 subviews of `TrollCalendarView` called `PlatformView` intended to contain 2D draw objects arranged around the center of `TrollCalendarView` in a 7-sided arrangement. So when the iPad is rotated, these 7 views rotate such that they are always oriented with the cardinal directions.

Each of the `PlatformView` subviews contains 3 subviews called `Tower`. Each tower contains 2D draw objects implemented in `drawRect:`.

So, in summary, I have `TrollCalendarView` with empty `drawRect:`, and subviews `PlatformView` and `Platformview` -> Tower that each have drawRect implementations. Additionally, Tower lies within the bounds of Platform, and Platform lies within the bounds of TrollCalendarView.

In `TrollCalendarView` I've added a swipe recognizer. When I swipe happens, a property is updated, and I call `[self setNeedsDisplay]` but nothing seems to happen. I added NSLog entries to `drawRect:` method in each of these views, and only the `TrollCalendarView` `drawRect:` method is called. Ironically, that is the one view whose `drawRect` method will be empty.

There is no xib file.

What do I need to do to ensure the `drawRect` method in the other subviews is called? Is there documentation somewhere that describes all the nuances that could affect this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I'm struggling with setNeedsDisplay. I thought it was supposed to trigger calls of drawRect for the view for which it is called and the hierarchy below that if it's within the view's bounds

No, that is not the case.  Where did you get that idea?

`-setNeedsDisplay:` applies only to the view to which it is sent. If you need to invalidate other views, you need to add some code to send `-setNeedsDisplay:` to them, too. That's all there is to it.

Comment: I got that idea from the answers to similar questions right here on stackoverflow. Just search subview setNeedsDisplay for samples. There are several.

Comment: I will follow this suggestion unless I learn of another way. It at least matches my findings in testing.

Comment: There's unfortunately a lot of noise on SO and a lot of blind-leading-the-blind. The questions you're looking at have very few votes, so probably not many people have seen them or had a chance to correct them. If you're just getting started, the Apple docs are a lot more reliable.

Comment: Thanks. It worked after I did the send to all relevant views.

Answer (score 5):

I think this is an optimization in the framework; if your subviews don't *need* to draw again, then this is a major performance improvement. Realize that almost anything animatable does not require drawrect (moving, scaling, etc).

If you *know* that all of your subviews should be redrawn (and not simply moved), then override setNeedsDisplay in your main view and do like this:

```
-(void) setNeedsDisplay {
    [self.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(setNeedsDisplay)];
    [super setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

I have tested this, and it causes all subviews to be redrawn as well. Please note that you will earn efficiency karma points if you somehow filter your subviews and make sure you only send that to subviews which *actually need redrawn*... and even more if you can figure out how *not* to need to redraw them. :-)

Comment: Thanks. I will try that. In my scenario, the 7 platform subviews will not need to be redrawn. Exactly two thirds of the remaining 21 subviews will be guaranteed to need to be redrawn. Knowing which of the 21 need to be redrawn is calculated efficiently in drawRect and can't be done more efficiently elsewhere. Just curious - how does the framework veto my decision (your optimization comment)? Seems like that defeats the purpose of having setNeedsDisplay in the first place.

Comment: Nope. Doesn't work. This gets only the subviews. I need the subviews of those subviews to be redrawn. I've decided to do the work of walking the tree at the point where I need to set setNeedsDisplay. Thanks for the suggestion, though.